# train, dev set and test set advices for implementation and hyperameter tuning

Tags: machine-learning

I have some doubts about the implementation and tuning of parameters and hyperparameters by using the classic train, validation and test set. So it would be of great help if somebody could clarify me these concepts and bring me some hints for its implementation in a language like Python.

For example, if I have a Neural Network, for what I know the parameter tuning (lets consider the number of hidden layers and neurons per layer), could be tuned with the training set. So when it comes to the validation set, which is approximately 20% of the dataset, I can tune my hyperparameters with the following algorithm:

Example: Tuning batch size and learning rate:

```
hyperListB=[]
hyperListL=[]

//let´s suppose both lists have the same dimensions
for i in range(0,hyperListB):
   model=fit(train_set,hyperListB[i],hyperlistL[i]
   values[].add(evaluate(model,validation_set)  //add scores of each run
end for

for i in range(0,values):
   plot_loss_functions(values)

select best set of hyperparameters

model=fit(test_set, selecter_hyperparameters)
evaluate(model)
```

would this sequence of steps be correct? I have searched thru different pages and did not find something that could help me with this. Please, bear in mind that I do not want to use cross-validation or other library-based techniques such as GridSearchCV.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a Train validation test split, the fit method on the train data.

Validation data is used for hyperparameter tuning. A set of hyperparameters is selected and the model is trained on the train set. Then this model will be evaluated on the validation set. This is repeated until all permutations of the different hyperparameters have been exhausted.

The best set of hyperparameters are the ones that gave the best result on the validation set. This method is called Grid search.

The test set is used to evaluate the model with the best hyperparameters selected. THis gives the final unbiased accuracy and loss.
The fit method will never be called on the validation or test set.

your example will look like:

```
hyperListB=[]
hyperListL=[]

//let´s suppose both lists have the same dimensions
for hyperB in hyperListB:
    for hyperL in hyperListL:
        model=fit(train_set,hyperB,hyperL)
        values[].add(evaluate(model,validation_set)  //add scores of each run
     end for
end for
for i in range(0,values):
   plot_loss_functions(values)

select best set of hyperparameters

evaluate(model,test_set)
```